# Can I apply a texture to UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, colors, textures, uitoolbar

I tried doing this:

```
[toolbar setTint:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thingFromMyBundle.png"]]];
```

but it just ended up black. At first I assumed you weren't allowed to "tint" with a texture, but I've seen apps recently that can do this. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add 2 files to your project, call them `UINavigationBar-CustomTexture.h` and `UINavigationBar-CustomTexture.m` for example, in those files put this:

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface UINavigationBar (CustomTexture)
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "UINavigationBar-CustomTexture.h"

@interface UIView (CustomTexture)
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx;
@end

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomTexture)
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    if ([self isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]]){
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, -image.size.height, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage);
    }else{
        [super drawLayer:layer inContext:ctx];
    }
}
@end
```

Include the .h file where you instantiate your navigation controller.
Make your png file 320x44. Depending on your texture, change the tint color of your navigation bar to something like this (to make the buttons on the navigation bar look better):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:0.5f alpha:0.1f]];
```

Comment: It works for me, but I'm getting an "<Error>: doClip: empty path.".
If I remove the CGContextClip(ctx); them the warning goes away (and everything still works).

Comment: A category really isn't a good way to handle custom drawing in general. You're overriding the standard implementation (if there is one) of UINavigationBar and never calling that implementation. Subclassing is the proper way of handling it, but it requires a little more work setting the class of the navigation bar in the xib file, but is far more future proof.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got around this problem:

```
_titleToolbar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, kDeviceWidth, 34.0f)];
[_titleToolbar setTranslucent:YES];
[_titleToolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

CALayer* backgroundLayer = [CALayer layer];
[backgroundLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kDeviceWidth, _titleToolbar.frame.size.height)];

UIImage* patternImage = [UIImage deviceImageNamed:@"topToolbarBackground"];
[backgroundLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage].CGColor];
[[_titleToolbar layer] insertSublayer:backgroundLayer atIndex:0];
```